# PySpark: How to write a Spark dataframe having a column with type SparseVector into CSV file?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a spark dataframe which has one column with type spark.mllib.linalg.SparseVector:

1) how can I write it into a csv file?

2) how can I print all the vectors?

Answer (score 4):

To write the dataframe to a csv file you can use the standard     `df.write.csv(output_path)`.

However, if you just use the above you are likely to get the `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: CSV data source does not support struct<type:tinyint,size:int,indices:array<int>,values:array<double>> data type` error for the column with the SparseVector type.

There are two ways to print the SparseVector and avoid that error: the sparse format or the dense format.

If you want to print in the dence format, you can define udf like this:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

dense_format_udf = udf(lambda x: ','.join([str(elem) for elem in x], StringType())

df = df.withColumn('column_name', dense_format_udf(col('column_name')))

df.write.option("delimiter", "\t").csv(output_path)
```

The column outputs to something like this in the dense format: `1.0,0.0,5.0,0.0`

If you want to print in the sparse format, you can utilize [the OOB `__str__` function of the SparseVector class](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.0/api/python/pyspark.mllib.linalg-pysrc.html#SparseVector.__str__), or be creative and define your own output format. Here I am going to use the OOB function.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

sparse_format_udf = udf(lambda x: str(x), StringType())

df = df.withColumn('column_name', sparse_format_udf(col('column_name')))

df.write.option("delimiter", "\t").csv(output_path)
```

The column prints to something like this in the sparse format `(4,[0,2],[1.0,5.0])`

Note I have tried this approach before: `df = df.withColumn("column_name", col("column_name").cast("string"))` but the column just prints to something like this `[0,5,org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.UnsafeArrayData@6988050,org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.UnsafeArrayData@ec4ae6ab]` which is not desirable.

Comment: Thanks, this is useful, but didn't you mix up sparse and dense in udf names? I.e. `1.0,0.0,5.0,0.0` should be dense with dense_format_udf , while `(4,[0,2],[1.0,5.0])` should be sparse format and sparse_format_udf?

Answer (score 2):

1. https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv
2. `df2 = df1.map(lambda row: row.yourVectorCol)`

   OR `df1.map(lambda row: row[1])`

   where you either have a named column or just refer to the column by its position in the row.

   Then, to *print* it, you can `df2.collect()`

Without more information, this may be helpful to you, or not helpful enough to you. Please elaborate a bit.